# Wamp64, PHP7, Laravel 5.2, tmp folder dosnt store files

Tags: wamp, laravel-5

So im using wamp64 with php7 im trying to upload images.
my form looks likes this:

```
<form  method="POST" action="/dashboard/nalaz/dodaj/{{ $patients->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="images[]">
</form>
```

this is my php.ini file uploads configuration

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir ="C:/wamp64/tmp"
upload_max_filesize = 3M
max_file_uploads = 5
```

Now i do this in my laravel controller

```
$temp = tmpfile();
$images = $request->file('reportimages');
dd($images);
```

dd() gives me the array of uploaded files

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => UploadedFile {#363 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "11082663_10205108991016758_689124932158641809_n.jpg"
    -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
    -size: 42149
    -error: 0
    path: "C:\wamp64\tmp"
    filename: "php95FE.tmp"
    basename: "php95FE.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php95FE.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php95FE.tmp"
    aTime: 2016-05-12 10:21:16
    mTime: 2016-05-12 10:21:16
    cTime: 2016-05-12 10:21:16
    inode: 0
    size: 42149
    perms: 0100666
    owner: 0
    group: 0
    type: "file"
    writable: true
    readable: true
    executable: false
    file: true
    dir: false
    link: false
    linkTarget: "C:\wamp64\tmp\php95FE.tmp"
  }
]
```

but NOTHING gets written to "C:/wamp64/tmp"
so it cannot actually save the immage because there is no image in the tmp folder

I am on windows and I granted all permissions for all users for the tmp folder.

Comment: Its always a good idea to learn a bit of PHP before wrapping it in a framework

Comment: im sorry am a rooky @RiggsFolly . So you know the solution to my issue?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses and look for `File Downloads`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the PHP Manual on file uploads](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> The file will be deleted from the temporary directory at the end of the request if it has not been moved away or renamed.

And Laravel's `dd()` ends script execution, so after that, the file is gone.

But renaming uploaded files is trivial, PHP even has a designated function to do just that: [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: the thing is, i open my tmp folder lol, and i am watching it while I send the request, but nothing appears even for a milisecond. Should it appear at least for a moment until it reaches dd()?

Comment: and I discovered this before i was using dd(). I couldnt save the image because it couldnt be found in the tmp folder.

Comment: Depending on the implementation of PHP or MSVCRT, the file might not even have been flushed to the disk before the delete was issued. And even if it had been, chances are Windows explorer doesn't check back often enough (if at all) to catch the file in the process. What happens if you put a `sleep(10);` before `dd`?